# Why isn't vertical-align: text-bottom working?

Tags: css

I can't get text-bottom to work properly. From what I'm reading the div should be aligned by the bottom of the text, however it's aligning it on the bottom as if its being aligned by "bottom".

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: text-bottom; //same as bottom
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

div:first-child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  line-height: 100px;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>hello</div>
<div>world</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

"should be aligned by the bottom of the text..." - that's `vertical-align: baseline`, which is the default setting for inline-blocks, so you can simply erase that property completely, and the DIVs will align along their lowest text lines:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

div:first-child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  line-height: 100px;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>hello</div>
<div>world</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Text-align is meant to align items with the **parent**'s text, not the sibling's

```css
main{
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;

}

div:first-child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  line-height: 100px;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<main>
  Text
  <div>hello</div>
  <div>world</div>
</main>
```

You can still get away with it if only set it on one of them instead of both though

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

div:first-child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  line-height: 100px;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  vertical-align: text-bottom; 
}
```

```html
<div>hello</div>
<div>world</div>
```